# Show Leaderboard Score Directly - Google Play Service

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, leaderboard

I want to show leaderboard score directly as player press on leaderboard icon as like this:

[image]

When I was showing a leaderboard it just displaying, list of leaderboard. I want to see actual score directly.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public void ShowLeaderboard ()
 {
     if (Social.localUser.authenticated)
         Social.ShowLeaderboardUI ();
     else {
         // authenticate user:
         Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
             // handle success or failure
             if (success) {
                 Debug.Log ("Login Success....");
                 PostHighScoreOnLeaderBoard();
                 Social.ShowLeaderboardUI ();
             } else {
                 Debug.Log ("Login Failed....");
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

How can I show directly a players score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like the show the user's score directly like in your first image, you need to call PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("leaderboard_id") with the leaderboard ID passed in instead of Social.ShowLeaderboardUI().

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to show a particular leaderboard instead of all leaderboards, you can pass a leaderboard ID to the method. This, however, is a Play Games extension, so the Social.Active object needs to be cast to a PlayGamesPlatform object first:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
...
// show leaderboard UI
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("Cfji293fjsie_QA");
```